# Google Cloud Scheduler - HTTP headers not respected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm trying to send push to my app using Google Cloud Scheduler:

```
gcloud beta scheduler jobs create http PUSH --schedule="0 * * * *" --uri="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" --description="desc" --headers="Authorization: key=<AUTHKEY> --http-method="POST" --message-body="{\"to\":\"/topics/allDevices\",\"priority\":\"low\",\"data\":{\"success\":\"ok\"}}"
```

The result is always 401 Unauthorized. After issuing command:

```
gcloud beta scheduler jobs describe PUSH
```

I do not get these headers back:

```
description: desc
httpTarget:
  body: eyJ0byI6Ii90b3BpY3MvYWxsnByaW9yaXR5IjoRGV2aWNlcyIsIiaGlnaCIsImRhdGEiOnsic3VjY2VzcyI6Im9rIn19  <--- THIS IS WEIRD
  headers:
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream
    User-Agent: Google-Cloud-Scheduler
  httpMethod: POST
  uri: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
lastAttemptTime: '2018-11-07T20:32:37.657408Z'
name: projects/..../locations/europe-west1/jobs/PUSH
retryConfig:
  maxBackoffDuration: 3600s
  maxDoublings: 16
  maxRetryDuration: 0s
  minBackoffDuration: 5s
schedule: 0 * * * *
scheduleTime: '2018-11-07T21:00:00.681498Z'
state: ENABLED
status:
  code: 16
timeZone: Etc/UTC
userUpdateTime: '2018-11-07T20:29:15Z'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first question about body:

> body:eyJ0byI6Ii90b3BpY3MvYWxsnByaW9yaXR5IjoRGV2aWNlcyIsIiaGlnaCIsImRhdGEiOnsic3VjY2VzcyI6Im9rIn19
>   <--- THIS IS WEIRD

This is the base64 encoding of

> {\"to\":\"/topics/allDevices\",\"priority\":\"low\",\"data\":{\"success\":\"ok\"}}

Google is taking your `--message-body` and encoding it in `base64`.

Next regarding the header issue. You have a several errors in your '--headers`.

> --headers="Authorization: key=AUTHKEY

You are missing a quote mark after `AUTHKEY`. I will assume that this issue is just editing mistake creating the question. (Note I could not figure out how to include the less-than and greater-than characters in this response).

However, the syntax for `--headers` is wrong. The `--headers` expects `KEY=VALUE`, not `KEY:VALUE`. In this example the `KEY` is `Authorization` and the `VALUE` is `key=AUTHKEY`.

```
--headers="Authorization=key=AUTHKEY"
```

Comment: Thanks John! Had no idea about headers format - it helped! Still no luck in sending the push though: the only thing I see in logs is 
 httpRequest: {
  status:  200   
 }. Is there any way to see whatwas the actual http response?

Comment: It looks like Cloud Scheduler logs does not record the response headers or body other than status code. I verified this will my Cloud Scheduler calling Cloud Functions which returns a large HTTP body. I noticed that you are calling FCM. Can you view the logs on that side?

Comment: Suggestion: Create a Cloud Functions function and test with that as the HTTP destination. Your function can log the calling HTTP headers and body to verify that everything being sent to FCM looks good.

Comment: Here is another suggestion. Your HTTP headers have `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. I would change that to `Content-Type: application/json`. Example: `--headers="Authorization=key=AUTHKEY, Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: Example: `--headers="Authorization=key=AUTHKEY, Content-Type=application/json"`

Comment: Content-Type: application/json was the right solution. Thank you for your help!

Comment: A word for the Googlers: there seems to be no way to add custom headers through the cloud console, so to add a JSON payload you must use gcloud or another external tool.